When running Flask I get an import error from a module
I currently have a virtual environment created with python -m venv venv
I pip installed Flask and pypco.
When I run the following Flask server with flask run:
from flask import Flask
import os
import time
import pypco


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

I get the error:
Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypco'

I reinstalled the pypco a few times and still the error appears.  I'm not executing the module only importing it.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Download binaries directly https://pypi.org/project/pypco/#files and extract in same folder where ur code resides ... and Import from there .... I do faced this kind of issues with other libraries,,I follow to this to fix it and move forward
